# Shell if statements not working as intended

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I am attempting to create a search program in shell as an exercise, but when I try to handle empty lines with an if-statement I get a message saying that the shell encountered an unexpected operator.

```
    #!/bin/sh

file=$1
token=$2

while read line
do
    if [ ! -z $line ]
    then
      set $line
      if [ $1 = $token ] 
      then 
        echo $line
      fi
    fi
done < $file
```

When I run the program using `match_token animals_blanks dog` I get

```
./match_token: 8: [: cat: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: dog: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: dog: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: cow: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: lion: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: bear: unexpected operator
./match_token: 8: [: wolf: unexpected operator
```

The animals_blanks files contains:

```
cat meow kitten

dog ruff pup
dog bark

cow moo calf

lion roar cub

bear roar cub
wolf howl pup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable:

```
 if [ ! -z "$line" ]
```

but normally, one would write:

```
 if [ -n "$line" ]
```

When you leave the variable unquoted, the `[` command sees something like: `[ -n cat dog ]`, which is an error because it expects only one argument after `-n`.  By quoting the variable, the expression becomes `[ -n "cat dog" ]` which has only one argument, as expected by `[`.  Note that there's really no reason to do that test, or to use `set`; read can split the line for you when it reads:

```
while read animal sound offspring; do
    test "$animal" = "$token" && echo $animal $sound $offspring
done < $file
```