# Shell if Statement with either -z or -n not working

Tags: bash, shell

Good Night.

Im trying to use the following code to read each line of every life i have in a directory, line by line, where every line is delimited by ";", to show me every line that has something in the last delimited field but my if statements are not working.

Here are some examples of lines.

```
Name_familyName;1234567890;service_name;date_time_contract;date_time_purchase
Name_familyName;1234567890;service_name;date_time_contract;
```

As you can see some times i have the date_time_purchase value in the last field but some times i dont, i was trying to use the following code to check if the line has data in the last field and to show me.

```
#!/bin/bash

files_dir="/directory/sub_directory/*"


for file in $files_dir
do

    total_lines=$(wc -l <$file)
    i=0

    while IFS= read -r line; do


        i=$(($i+1))

        last_field=$(echo "$line" | rev | cut -d";" -f1 | rev)

        if [[ "$total_lines" -gt "$i" ]] && [[ ! -z "$last_field" ]]; then
            info=$(echo $line)
            echo $info

        fi
    done < "$file"

done
```

I also tried using [[ -n $last_field ]] but it shows me the lines without the last field regardless, i also tried to use them with and without the "!" mark.

I also looked into this but it didnt work either:
[Shell if statements not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513397/shell-if-statements-not-working-as-intended)

Comment: you should run your code through shellcheck.net .

Comment: it doesn't show me anything besides Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Im getting exactly what i put in the example of line and i expect to get only the lines with data on the very last field. the date_time_purchase field

Comment: For the line `while IFS= read -r line; do`, should it be `IFS=";"`?

Comment: @Guest first i get the file and then i read each line of it, beside im going to threat every line differently  depending if it has data in the last field or not.

Comment: Are you sure the last field is completely empty after the semi-colon in your files, that they does not contain any hidden characters like a carriage return?

Comment: @Michael: Seems probable, it works for me. Might be a space, too.

Comment: For debugging I would also put an echo statement after setting a variable, something like `echo "${#last_field}:[$last_field]"` so you can confirm what it contains that is being tested.

Comment: ill check if it is a space

Comment: Are you simply trying to return the last field for every line? (eg. `date_time_purchase`, or `date_time_contract`)?

Comment: @Michael it is not spaces

Comment: @l'L'l i want it to show me only the line with date_time_purchase

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man did you do the debug line to confirm that $last_field was zero length before the test and not a hidden character?  Even if there were spaces in the source files they should be lost in your assignment anyway as it was not quoted.

Comment: yea it is suppose to be empty, i printed it a bunch of times and even checked on the files themselves.

Comment: if MS-Windows was involved in any aspect of  your script of data, check fro MS-DOS line endings with `cat -vet file` . If you see `^M$` at the end-of-lines, use `dos2unix file` to remove the `^M`s. (also "known" as `\r`). Good luck.

Comment: Extending @shellter's recommendation: if you use `LC_ALL=C cat -vet file`, it'll show nonprinting unicode characters (like nonbreaking spaces) as well as ASCII control characters. If you do that and the lines with supposedly blank last fields end with ";$", they're really blank. If they end with "; $", you've got a space there. ";^M$" would mean a carriage return, ";^I$" would mean a tab, and ";M-BM- $" would mean a nonbreaking space.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Checking the file is not enough, you need to be sure about what is in the variable that the `if` statement is seeing.  The code itself is correct, and copy and pasting your two lines of test data works.  That means needing to ensure the variable contains what is expected and working backwards from there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
files_dir="/directory/sub_directory"
for file in "$files_dir"/*
do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
  while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
  do
    [[ "$f5" ]] || echo "$f1;$f2;$f3;$f4;$f5"
  done < "$file"
done
```

What I changed :

- I put the glob in the `for` statement : doing the globbing there prevents quoting issues
- I added a test to make sure the `file` variable contains a file, as a failed glob could make it otherwise
- I got rid of the `total_lines` and `i` variables that, to the best of my understanding, actually did nothing (the condition they were used in seemed superfluous)
- I replaced the pipe with a direct `read` statement in the while loop that breaks the line using semi-colons (`IFS=";"`) and assigns the five fields.
- Using `[[ "$var" ]]` does the same thing as `[[ ! -z "$var" ]]`, but is simpler and easier to read.
- Using a command substitution `$()` with an `echo` inside to assign a variable, and then echoing this value in a second statement, is redundant.  Just one echo statement, without substitution, is enough.

Please note that in two instances I use the `||` "OR" logical operator.  The result is that the statement following the test is executed only if the test fails.  It is more concise than a full `if/then/fi`.  The `continue` keyword allows early termination of the current iteration and skips to the next iteration.  It differs from `break`, which would exit the loop, skipping all remaining iterations, not just the current one.

Comment: nothing happened. do i need to add the if before the []??

Comment: Nothing happened after you did what?  You need to replace the whole code with the one I proposed, and make sure that "/directory/sub_directory" existes contains the files you need to process.  This code will not process files in sub-directories of "/directory/sub_directory" (nor did the code in your question).

Comment: it some what works, if i ask to print all fields individually in the first if statement it prints them without problems, it even prints the last field either it having data or not, but the second if statement doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Fred Whilst I do not necessarily disagree with your solution, I too would have read the fields into different variables, you are wrong to say piping through `rev` does not work.  You can test it yourself.  A line without a date_time_purchase ends in a separator, so reversing it would see it begin with one, and so `cut` would return a blank field 1.  It may not be the most efficient method, but it is a valid one.

Comment: @Michael I missed the final separator.  I will update my answer to remove the incorrect statement.